# antiforgerytoken in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, antiforgerytoken

I have a `.Html` page which allows the user to fill in a form and submit it, however in `MVC` we could use an `AntiforgeryToken` to insure the request has came from the correct place.

I'm currently studying `AngularJS` and I'm curious how I go about validating the same situation, I'm currently not using the `.cshtml` instead I have the plain `.html` page, I am however building this project within `visual studio` can someone shed some knowledge on how I go about using the `AntiforgeryToken` or something similar to validate each request via `AngularJS`

I have googled this but the responses I get and dicussing `MVC`.

Comment: There are lot to be _googled_ I guess. **[Google 1](http://techbrij.com/angularjs-antiforgerytoken-asp-net-mvc)**, **[Google 2](http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/)**, **[Google 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460196/angularjs-web-api-antiforgerytoken-csrf)**. I wonder did you miss these or they don't match your requirement.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Just looking at google 1 option, the first part is the function GetAntiForgeryToken where does this part go exactly? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: **[Here is the link to download complete project](https://github.com/techbrij/angularjs-asp-net-mvc)**.. Please download and walkthrough..