# Form doesn't have duplicate key still getting "The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted" error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, antiforgerytoken

I have used `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in my main .cshtml page `<div ng-controller="MainController as vm">`
I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460196/angularjs-web-api-antiforgerytoken-csrf) to implement.

```
var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
                var tokenCookie = headers
                    .GetCookies()
                    .Select(c => c["__RequestVerificationToken_L21vYmlsZQ2"]) //AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                var tokenHeader = string.Empty;
                if (headers.Contains("X-XSRF-Token"))
                {
                    tokenHeader = headers.GetValues("X-XSRF-Token").FirstOrDefault();
                    AntiForgery.Validate(tokenCookie != null ? tokenCookie.Value : null, tokenHeader);
                }
```

`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is generating key (eg: "xyz123") while validating in `OnActionExecuting()` I'm getting different key (eg: "pqr678") and in `AntiForgery.Validate(tokenCookie != null ? tokenCookie.Value : null, tokenHeader);` getting following error

The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys.

Note: I do not have a duplicate token and I also tried to add a machine key in web.config [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402210/the-anti-forgery-token-could-not-be-decrypted)

Comment: Why you select `__RequestVerificationToken_L21vYmlsZQ2` cookie? Doesn't it suppose to be `__RequestVerificationToken`?

Comment: @WillHuang , In `actionContext.Request.Headers` the name is `__RequestVerificationToken_L21vYmlsZQ2`, I tried with `__RequestVerificationToken` and `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName` but this didn't worked.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project to GitHub so that I can understand what's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ValidateAntiForgeryKey attribute on your action.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
{

}
```

Also, you can try to add the validationKey="AutoGenerate" on the machine config. like below:

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate">
```